# Incomplete List when retrieve - Java App Engine One-to-many Relationship

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, jdo, datanucleus

I'm developing on Google App Engine - Java, I have a problem when getting Child Object (List - Owned Relationship one-to-many) of Persistent in Datastore.
Here is code of Item class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Item
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key id;
    @Persistent
    String idfb, content;
    GeoPt point;
    Date datetime;
    int status;
    @Persistent(mappedBy="item", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    List<Comment> comment = new ArrayList<Comment>();
    @Persistent(mappedBy="item", defaultFetchGroup="true")
    @Element(dependent = "true")
    List<Vote> vote = new ArrayList<Vote>();
    // getter and setter.....
}
```

Comment class:

```
@PersistenceCapable(identityType = IdentityType.APPLICATION, detachable = "true")
public class Comment
{
    @PrimaryKey
    @Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
    Key id;
    String idfb, content;
    Date datetime;
    GeoPt point;
    Item item;
    // getter and setter....
}
```

And code of ItemEndpoint (i've added new method called comment)

```
@Api(name = "itemendpoint", namespace = @ApiNamespace(ownerDomain = "uet.com", ownerName = "uet.com", packagePath = "mhst"))
public class ItemEndpoint
{
    // auto-generate method listItem, remove, update....
    // here is code of method getItem
    @ApiMethod(name = "getItem")
    public Item getItem(@Named("id") Long id)
    {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Item item = null;
        try
        {
            item = mgr.getObjectById(Item.class, id);
        }
        finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }
        return item;
    }
    // i've added new method called comment
    @ApiMethod(name = "comment")
    public void comment(@Named("idstt") Long idstt, Comment cm)
    {
        PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Item item = null;
        try
        {
            mgr.currentTransaction().begin();
            item = mgr.getObjectById(Item.class, idstt);
            List<Comment> _cm = item.getComment();
            if (!_cm.contains(cm))
                _cm.add(cm);
            else if (_cm.contains(cm)) _cm.remove(cm);
            item.setComment(_cm);
            mgr.makePersistent(item);
            mgr.currentTransaction().commit();
        }
        finally
        {
            mgr.close();
        }   
    }
}
```

The `comment` method will add a Comment object to `Item.comment` field.
At first, I've added an Item with 2 Comment object in `List<Comment> comment` to Datastore.
My problem is when I call `getItem` on Android client, server return an `Item` object, and then I call `item.getComment`, it return a `List<Comment>` with `size() = 2`, but when i get an element of this List, it return `null`.
However, then I re-Deploy my App-Engine-BackEnd project to GAE, I retried and it return true Object exactly.
But then, when I call `comment` method, it add a new `Comment` object to the List `Item.comment` in Datastore, and it repeats the above problem, I call `item.getComment`, it return a `List<Comment>` with `size() = 3`, the first and second element are right as above(re-Deploy), but the last element which i've added by call `comment` method, it is `null`. And I have to deploy again to make it work properly.
Anyone can explain this problem? or what's wrong with my code?
Sorry for my bad english, thanks for reading!